# How to include Twilio account/number properties as params in Webhook post?

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I am using Twilio to forward incoming SMS to email, using a self-hosted php webhook page, which sends the SMS as an email.

I'd like to include some info from the Twilio account/number in the webhook params - specifically the Twilio "Friendly Name" for the number. And if it's possible, additional user-configurable text for the number (though I don't see anywhere I could configure any more info).

Is "Friendly Name" (and other acct info) available to add to the webhook URL?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to look at the Webhook URL parameters is send them to a tool like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download), and then use the Ngrok Debug (http://127.0.0.1:4040) to view them.

You can pull the Friendly Name using the [IncomingPhoneNumbers API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource) or better yet, send the friendlyName as a URL query parameter at the end of your webhook.

```
AccountSid
AddOns
ApiVersion
Body
From
FromCity
FromCountry
FromState
FromZip
MessageSid
NumMedia
NumSegments
SmsMessageSid
SmsSid
SmsStatus
To
ToCity
ToCountry
ToState
ToZip
```

Comment: I don't see friendlyName in your list there... how you would you "include it as a URL query parameter at the end of the webhook"?

Comment: So, the URL you point the Twilio Number and then append a `?friendlyName=winston`. More details of the concept here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications.